# Debounce API call in redux

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to send analytics data to google and need to make an API. I have a search box that filters a list of customers. The search itself is debounced every 300ms but I only want to send the search data to GA every 1000ms.

I am trying to use the [redux-debounced](https://github.com/ryanseddon/redux-debounced) middleware. But I noticed it only helps in delaying the updating of the state. I am trying to use it with redux-thunk. [I saw an issue where someone already asked](https://github.com/ryanseddon/redux-debounced/issues/4). I tried whats already written there and it didn't work.

This is what my thunk and middle wares looks like

```
let store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(logger, createDebounce(), thunkMiddleware)
);

export function trackCustomerSearch(key) {
  const thunk = dispatch => {
    console.log(key); //This should be only logged only once for 1000ms
    ... //make api call to GA
  };

  thunk.meta = {
    debounce: {
      time: 1000
    }
  };

  return thunk;
}
```

Am I missing something? Or is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1):

Time to write your own middleware. It's not very hard, and you can make it do exactly what you want.

```
const debounceInterval = 1000;
let timerRef = null;

const updateGAMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type === 'USER_UPDATED_SEARCH_FIELD') {
    // if my timeout hasn't passed, exit early
    if (timerRef) return next(action);

    // send update to GA here
    // (presumably search field value is in action.data)

    timerRef = setTimeout(() => { timerRef = null; }, debounceInterval); 
  }
  return next(action);
};

export default updateGAMiddleware;
```

Then you just import and include this middleware like-a so:

```
...
import updateGAMiddleware from './<somewhere_sane>';
let store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(logger, updateGAMiddleware, thunkMiddleware)
);
```

And then you can dispatch `USER_UPDATED_SEARCH_FIELD` actions as much as you want because they'll only be sent to GA at most every second.

I don't know if you still need the other debounced middleware. If you only care about how often you post to GA and not about how often you update the state tree, then maybe you don't.

Hopefully that was what you were going for. If not, please clarify and I'll do what I can to help. Otherwise, good luck!